# Convergence of double series $\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb Z} c_n \bar{c}_m \frac{\sin(n-m)}{n-m}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let
$$\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb Z} c_n \bar{c}_m \frac{\sin(n-m)}{n-m}$$
where $c_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers for which $\sum_n |c_n|^2<\infty$; $\bar{c}_m$ is complex conjugate of $c_m$.

Does $\sum_n |c_n|^2<\infty$ implies the convergence of this double series? Even if it were true I do not know to prove it. However, for example, I know that
$$\sum_n \frac{\sin n}{n}$$
converges. Then, why should not converge also double series? Finally, note that for $n=m$ we have
$$\sum_{n} |c_n|^2$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{n,m} c_n \bar{c}_m \frac{\sin(n-m)}{n-m}=\sum_{n} |c_n|^2+\sum_{n,m, n\neq m} c_n \bar{c}_m \frac{\sin(n-m)}{n-m}$$

**EDIT**
For $r\in\mathbb Z$ write
\begin{equation}
 \alpha_r=
   \begin{cases}
   \frac{ 1}{r}  \qquad &r \not= 0,\\
   0\qquad & r=0,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
The so-called “Hilbert's double series theorem” says: given (real or complex) sequences $x = (x_j )$ and $y = (y_k)$, let
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\alpha_{j-k} x_j y_k.$$
Then
$$|u(x,y)|^2\leq \pi \sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} |x_j|^2 \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} |y_k|^2$$
From this, we have
$$\left|\sum_{n,m, n\neq m} c_n \bar{c}_m \frac{\sin(n-m)}{n-m}\right|^2\leq \pi \left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} |c_j|^2\right)^2$$
Therefore the double series here proposed converges.

Comment: Most important question (for me and perhaps others): how does a multiple series is carried on? I mean, do you first *fix* one of the indexes and makes the other one run, or you mix the indexes Cauchy-wise (i.e. taking all the indexes $\;n,m\;$ s.t. $\;n+m=k\;,\;\;k\;$ some fixed natural/integer)....? I honestly don't know, and I've this feeling many around here also don't know, so it is going to be tough to offer you any real help here.

Comment: You're right. Maybe this post is too general. I delete it.

Comment: I don't think you've to delete it: chances are *somebody* really knows and can help us with this.

Comment: @Timbuc, I've edited my post and I've proposed an approach.